# What is "private browsing" used for?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

What is it when you are in "private" from the home screen?   What does private browsing do for me and what are the pros and cons in using it?

Answer (score 1):

> Private Browsing protects your private information and blocks some websites from tracking your behavior. Safari won't remember the pages you visit, your search history, or your AutoFill information.

<sup>Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203036</sup>